# No module named 'aiohttp'

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I  use python3.
My python program is complaining: ***ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'***

I tried 'pip install aiohttp' --- which  shows **'Requirement already satisfied'** , but   I still get the same error.

I changed   requirements.txt
from aiohttp==3.8.5 to 3.8.6

but 'pip3 install -r requirements.txt' gives a new error :
***ERROR: No matching distribution found for arandr==0.1.10***

Is there a way to force the dependencies to be installed? Or should I pip3 install arandr?
Thanks a tonne,Peter

Comment: You use `pip` and `pip3` interchangeably: can you run `pip --version` and `pip3 --version` to double-check that?

Comment: This is also "a" reason why virtual environments are encouraged.

Comment: If you have multiple interpreters, check which one is selected in you IDE. 
That can be a cause also.

Comment: pip and pip3 show same thing (see  below)

C:\>pip --version
pip 23.2.1 from C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
C:\>pip3 --version
pip 23.2.1 from C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)

I will investigate what Python version is being used in VSCode debugger.
Thanks.

Comment: In vs code, I  downgraded the python interpreter from 3.11.5  to 3.10.4 , and it works. Thanks again.